# Abstract base manager isn't accessible

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a new user, but I get this message:

**_*get*_
    raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % type._*name*_)
AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via CompanyUser instances**

This is what I'm doing:

```
  def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        bundle = super(AccountCreateResource, self).obj_create(bundle)
        bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))

        bundle.obj.objects.create_user()
    except IntegrityError:
        raise BadRequest('Username already exists')
```

I should beable to access the manager. This is my model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class EmailUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves an EmailUser with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = EmailUserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, is_staff=False, is_active=True,
                          is_superuser=False, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class AbstractEmailUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Abstract User with the same behaviour as Django's default User but
    without a username field. Uses email as the USERNAME_FIELD for
    authentication.

    Use this if you need to extend EmailUser.

    Inherits from both the AbstractBaseUser and PermissionMixin.

    The following attributes are inherited from the superclasses:
        * password
        * last_login
        * is_superuser
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255,
                              unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = EmailUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the email.
        """
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        """
        Returns the email.
        """
        return self.email

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email])


class CompanyUser(AbstractEmailUser):
    """
    Concrete class of AbstractEmailUser.

    """

    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)


    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. This line - the one that's causing the error -  makes no sense:

```
bundle.obj.objects.create_user()
```

Since you haven't provided the code for `bundle`, I have to guess that this is a model with an `obj` ForeignKey, which points to `CompanyUser` (rather strange naming conventions, though). But as the error says, you can't call `objects` on an instance, only on the class. But even if you could, the line still doesn't make sense: `obj` is already a User, so why would you want to create one? And again, `create_user` takes at least an email parameter, which you're not supplying.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show enough of the code or the traceback to understand what's really going on, but anyway: the error message you get means you tried to access the Manager from an instance, and it's not allowed, period - the fact that you have an abstract model is totally irrelevant. You have to access the Manager from the model class itself. Hopefully it's just a matter of replacing `instance.objects` by `type(instance).objects`.